# Estonian named entity recognition data

Tags: nlp, language

I'm looking for estonian named entity recognition data. Till now I am unable to find one. Although Estonia has 90% of it's Govt services online, I can't find their NER data anywhere. I tried estnltk, but that library has a C++ code compatibility issue which is to be solved in future releases, and I can't use any command from the library.